# didFinishNavigation not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I'm trying to load a web page in a WKWebView control without loading it as a subview:

```
WKPreferences *preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = YES;
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.preferences = preferences;
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setValue:@"Safari" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-agent"];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

The url I'm trying to load is this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=mustang
```

The following `WKNavigationDelegate` method is not being called:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Result %@", result);
    }];
}
```

My NSObject class conforms to the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol.

Do I need to do something else?

Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a WK Scheme Handler in my code and I used it for tracking requests done and completed (amongst other things).

It showed that if one resource load failed, the didFinishNavigation: did not get called.

So, your content needs to load in its entirety for this to ever be called.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the same URL seems to work for me.

Do note:
The didFinishNavigation method is called after main frame load completes (this includes loading stuff from other hosts which are present in the main frame). So if something would be responding slow the didFinishNavigation method won't be invoked until resolved.